# How to prove a language is decidable

Tags: formal-languages

I would like to see some proofs to show if a particular string in machine $M$ which DFA is decidable or not. I am trying to find some results on this but those are not appropriate. Any examples or proofs would be of great help.

The scenario I am trying to prove is

> If I have a language that contains $2$ words ($w_1$ and $w_2$), when I send these words to a machine $M$ which is $DFA$, then $M$ should accept/reject the language based on these conditions 
>      "$w_1$ is a substring of $w_2$, $w_1$ should not be empty and $w_1$ is not equal to $w_2$"

Comment: Should "s1 is subset of s2" be "s1 is **substring** of s2"?

Comment: "S1 is subset of S2"

Comment: What are S1 and S2? Are they subsets of the language $L(M)$ or strings of the language?

Comment: They are strings (s1 & s2) in language L(M), where "s1 is subset of s2"

Comment: Your question seems incomplete. A decidability problem must be stated in the form of a yes/no question. What is the question which you are trying to prove decidable?

Comment: Since $s1$ and $s2$ are strings, not sets, it makes no sense to say that $s1$ is a *subset* of $s2$. On the other hand, it does make sense to say that $s1$ is a *substring* of $s2$.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you need to show that the language $L(M)$ with the given characteristics is decidable. Is this correct?

Comment: Also, since $S_1$ is a **subset** of $S_2$, they must both be **subsets** of $L(M)$, not strings.

Comment: well, by rephrasing the question, If I have a language that contains 2 words (w1 and w2), When I send these words to a machine M which is dfa, then M should accept/reject the language based on these conditions "w1 is a substring of w2, w1 should not be empty and w1 is not equal to w2". Please let me know if I am clear

Comment: That is a much clearer explanation. I think you should edit your question with that information.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a question about a language. You say "I have a language that contains 2 words, $w1$ and $w2$. Are these the only words in your language? (They are the only words you mention.) A finite language is always decidable. But you are talking about a machine that determines whether certain properties hold for these two words. That question can be answered by a machine in finite time, but what does it have to do about decidability? If you mean to have a language of many strings, you need to explain what you have more clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show that a language is decidable, we need to create a Turing machine which will halt on **any** input string from the language's alphabet. Since $M$ is a dfa, we already have the Turing Machine and just need to show that the dfa halts on every input. To do this, pick a generic string, say $w$, and show that the machine $M$ will either accept or reject this string.

Comment: Any language accepted by a DFA (i.e. a regular language) is decidable. This is true since the DFA can be simulated by a Turing machine (DFA is weaker than Turing machine).

Comment: In particular every finite language is regular and thus decidable. Not sure you are saying your language only consists of $w_1$ and $w_2$, but in this case it would be decidable.

Comment: Will i be able to prove this using pumping lemma? or any other tool?

Comment: @DeepakMudiam No, you don't need to use the pumping lemma. You already know that $L(M)$ is regular because $M$ is a DFA.